# Read a list of numbers from string

Tags: c, stringstream, scanf, string-parsing

I want to read a list of space - separated numbers stored in a string.
I know how this can be done using `stringstream` in C++ -:

```
string s = "10 22 45 67 89";
stringstream ss(s);
int numbers[100];
int k=0, next_number;
while(ss>>next_number)
    numbers[k++]=next_number;
```

My question is how can we do this in C ?
I have read about `sscanf()` in C but I am not certain it can be useful here.

Comment: Have you tried to use sscanf() on the string? It is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* use `sscanf` here if you know the number of items you expect in the string:

```
char const *s = "10 22 45 67 89";

sscanf(s, "%d %d %d %d %d", numbers, numbers+1, numbers+2, numbers+3 numbers+4);
```

If, however, you don't know the number of items *a priori*, you might try tokenizing the input, then attempting to convert each item individually.

```
char s[] = "10 22 45 67 89";

char *n = strtok(s, " ");
do { 
    numbers[k++] = atoi(n);
} while (n = strtok(NULL, " "));
```

Note that `strtok` has quite an ugly interface--it modifies the string you pass to it, and requires that you use it roughly as above--you pass the input string in the first call, then pass NULL for the string to tokenize for subsequent calls until you reach the end of the string. It stores a pointer to the current location in the string internally, which also makes thread safety a problem.

You can also use `sscanf` with the `%n` conversion to count the number of characters already converted, but that's (IMO) in nearly direct competition with `strtok` for some of the ugliest code imaginable, and I can't handle posting two things like that in one day.

Answer (score 8):

Use `sscanf()` and `"%n` to know where to begin the next scan.

```
char *s = "10 22 45 67 89";
for (k=0; k<100; k++) {
  int n;
  int cnt = sscanf(s, "%d %n", numbers[k], &n);
  if (cnt != 1) break;
  s += n;
}
if (*s) Handle_DidNotEndCleanly();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the numbers does not matter, you can loop through the string backwards, one character at a time.

```
char s[] = "10 22 45 67 89";
int i;
int tmp=0;
int mult=1;
for(i=strlen(s)-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(s[i] != ' ') {
        tmp += (s[i]-'0') * mult;
        mult *= 10;
    } else {
        // your number is stored in tmp, do whatever you want with it
        tmp=0;
        mult=1;
    }
}
```

If you must loop through it in the forward direction, this method can still be used but you need more code.

This method does not require you to know the number of items in the string beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct ss {//Simple stringstream mock 
    const char *p;
} Ss;

Ss *ss_new(const char *s){
    Ss *ssp = malloc(sizeof(*ssp));
    ssp->p = s;
    return ssp;
}

bool ss_nextInt(Ss *ssp, int *v){
    char *endp;
    while(isspace(*ssp->p))
        ssp->p++;
    if(!*ssp->p)
        return false;
    *v = strtol(ssp->p, &endp, 10);
    if(ssp->p != endp){
        ssp->p = endp;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int main(){
    const char *s = "10 22 45 67 89";
    int numbers[100];
    int i, k=0, next_number;
    Ss *ssp =  ss_new(s);
    while(ss_nextInt(ssp, &next_number))
        numbers[k++]=next_number;
    free(ssp);
    for(i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `<string.h>` there are numerous options to split strings. [`strchr`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strchr&sektion=3), [`strspn`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strspn&sektion=3), and [`strpbrk`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strpbrk&sektion=3) to name a few. Along with the C90 function [`strtol`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strtol&sektion=3) for parsing numbers, defined in `<stdlib.h>`.

[`strpbrk`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strpbrk&sektion=3) and [`strtol`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strtol&sektion=3)

```
#include <stdlib.h> // strtol
#include <string.h> // strpbrk
...
const char *s = "10 22 45 67 89";
char *p = s;
int numbers[MAX_NUMBERS];
size_t i = 0;
do {
  p = strpbrk(p, "-0123456789");
  if (p == NULL) break;
  char *ptr;
  int n = (int)strtol(p, &ptr, 10);
  if (p == ptr) break; // in case *p == '-' and p[1] is not a number
  numbers[i++] = n;
} while (i < MAX_NUMBERS);
```

[`strpbrk`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strpbrk&sektion=3) take two strings and returns a pointer to the first occurrence of any of the characters provided in the second string, or `NULL` if none are found.

[`strtol`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strtol&sektion=3) takes a string, a pointer to fill, and a base. It returns a `long` parsed from the first string, and fills the pointer with the location of the end of the number, or the original string pointer if no number was read.